# Function Transformations: tranformation on a polynomial (also transformed)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, transformation

I have this polynomial in factored form that is already transformed:

> f(x) = $a(x-b)^2(x-c)$, where a,b,c are real constants

This function is then transformed to a new function g(x), the following transformations were applied to function f(x):

> 1) reflected in the x-axis
>
> 2) Horizontally stretched by a factor of 1/2
>
> 3) Horizontally translated 3 units to the right.

After these transformations the new function g(x), the graph of g(x)
goes thru the following points:

> 1) (-5,0)
>
> 2) (3,64)
>
> 3) (7,0)
>
> > FIND the values of a,b and c of the original function f(x)!
> >     End of Question

I tried to just plug in the points and then i would have a system of equations to solve. BUT it seems really difficult to solve these because the equation is non-linear.
SO I am guessing that there must be another way.
I can't think of what the other way could possibly be.

Here is my g(x) function:

> g(x) = $-a(0.5(x-b)-3)^2(0.5(x-c)-3)$ // Hope i got this part right

Hope someone out there can help out here.

Comment: That's the way to do it, and it's not all that complicated assuming you got $\,g(x)\,$ right. It helped if you posted it.

Comment: Hi dxiv, thanks for the reply, I will put the overall g(x) function that i think I got correct, i will re-edit the question to add my g(x) function.

Comment: Ok dxiv, i put in my g(x) function, take a look at it, let me know what you think in regards to g(x).

Comment: Yes, that is what I am having difficulty trying to understand, I also get 2 solutions setting each factor to zero.So I did not believe that one should get more than one value or choices for b,c. BUT your factor of 2 would not be correct because that would then be reciprocated to become 1/2 which would me it would cause a compression and not a stretch.

Comment: Also inside of your function f, you out x+3, which would mean translation to the left and not to the right, so it would have to be x-3. SO I don't think you got it correct dxiv.

Comment: Hi, in term of notation that I use is the following for function based notation: y = f(kx) where k >0, then the mapping notation says this (x,y) --> ((1/k)x,y). SO when applied point-wise a k-value being a positive whole number then gets reciprocated and every x-value would get multiplied by a fraction hence causing a compression.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but we use the term stretch to mean expansion.

Comment: SO my understanding is that when they say stretch by factor of 1/2, that is supposed to mean the k-factor, the value of k itself, but its supposed to cause an expansion which is called a stretch.

Comment: Expansion is to become bigger than the original. And compression means getting smaller. You are using the term as a general transformation term of Horizontal stretch/compression. I am saying look at my equation that I stated.

Comment: IN the books that i am using when they say factor, they refer to the k-value, so k=1/2, hence the effect of this k value is to multiply by 2 all the x-values.

Comment: So if the book said `stretch by 2` you would divide by $2$, instead? Sorry, but that makes no sense to me. Maybe you should quote the exact definition your book uses for `stretch`.

Comment: Stretch means make bigger. Compress means makes smaller. SO they would say Horizontally compress by factor 2, which means k=2, which means x-values get multiplied by 1/2, which would compress.

Comment: That is how the terminology is used.

Comment: `Stretch means make bigger` And `multiply` also means make `bigger`, *unless* the factor is $\lt 1$.  Sorry, but that's not the way I've seen `stretch` used in such contexts, so I'll better abstain from further comments, and remove my previous ones until you quote the exact definitions you are supposed to use.